# does webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota() apply to IndexedDB?

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

With the (deprecated, Chrome-proprietary) `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota()` method I can request persistent storage in Chrome.

Does this also apply to IndexedDB data or only for the filesystem API?

Background: I want to make IndexedDB really persistent, make it immune to any browser garbage collection / eviction (except manual user deletion) in order to save important data.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Chrome's old PersistentStorage mechanism only applies to the FileSystem API. The intent was to apply it to all storage types but the proposal fizzled and was not adopted by other browsers. (Like the FileSystem API itself.)

...

There's a newer proposal at: https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/

... whereby script can call `navigator.storage.persist()` to request the "persistent" permission. If granted, it makes the entire origin's storage (Indexed DB, Cache API, localStorage, etc) persistent, i.e. can only be cleared by explicit user action. Chrome is currently (circa August 2016) experimenting with this proposal - if you'd like to try it out, see: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage?hl=en

Comment: Yes but AFAIK the new feature is currently (Chrome 52) in BETA and normally not *generally* available (for example, a freely available JS library can't yet make use of it). So, there is currently no way to safely persist data!?

Comment: Correct. This is true for most browsers; storage is "best effort" but when space is tight they will evict data (based on various heuristics, e.g. least recently used origin) rather than fill the device and start failing operations.